# Spring: Difference of /** and /* with regards to paths

Tags: spring, resources, url-pattern

What's the difference between two asterisks instead of one asterisk when we refer to paths?

Earlier I was debugging my Spring 3 project. I was trying to add a .swf using

`<spring:url var="flashy" value="/resources/images/flash.swf"/>`

With my web.xml's ResourceServlet looking like

```
<servlet-name>Resource Servlet </servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
```

But unfortunately I was getting this error:

`WARN org.springframework.js.resources.ResourceServlet - An attempt to access a protected resource at /images/flash.swf was disallowed.`

I found it really strange since all my images in the `images` folder were accessed but how come my  .swf was "protected"?

Afterwards, I decided to change the `/resources/*` to `/resources/**` and it finally worked. My question is... why?

Comment: Are you sure that `/resources/**` works in `<url-pattern>`?

Comment: As a side note, [org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.x/api/org/springframework/js/resource/ResourceServlet.html) is deprecated. From the [Spring Web Flow Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/index.html): "Note that starting with version 3.0.4, the Spring Framework includes a replacement for the ResourceServlet (see the [Spring Framework documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources))."

Answer (score 63):

This is a *path pattern* that is used in [**Apache Ant**](https://ant.apache.org/) library. Spring team implements it and uses it throughout the framework.

---

Back to your problem. According to the Javadoc for [`AntPathMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html), it only has 3 rules:

1. `?` matches one character
2. `*` matches zero or more characters
3. `**` matches zero or more 'directories' in a path

---

### UPDATE 2022

In the latest Spring Framework versions there is a forth rule:

4. `{spring:[a-z]+}` matches the regexp `[a-z]+` as a path variable named "spring"

See the details in the latest (as of now) Spring Framework **version 5** Javadoc: [`AntPathMathcer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html).

Comment: Is it possible for `*` to match what `**` can't?

Comment: Note that Springs' AntPathMatcher contains bugs: it isn't fully conform the Ant Pattern Style. Example: `**/*.css` won't work for paths that start with a `/`, while it should according to Ant Style conventions.