# Disable Spring Security for OPTIONS Http Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

Is it possible to disable Spring Security for a type of HTTP Method?

We have a Spring REST application with services that require Authorization token to be attached in the header of http request. I am writing a JS client for it and using JQuery to send the GET/POST requests. The application is CORS enabled with this filter code.

```
doFilter(....) {

  HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
  httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
  httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
  Enumeration<String> headersEnum = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeaders("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
  StringBuilder headers = new StringBuilder();
  String delim = "";
  while (headersEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    headers.append(delim).append(headersEnum.nextElement());
    delim = ", ";
  }
  httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers.toString());
}
```

But when JQuery sends in the OPTIONS request for CORS, the server responds with Authorization Failed token. Clearly the OPTIONS request, lacks Authorization token. So is it possible to let the OPTIONS escape the Security Layer from the Spring Security Configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried this

> You can use multiple  elements to define different
>   access requirements for different sets of URLs, but they will be
>   evaluated in the order listed and the first match will be used. So you
>   must put the most specific matches at the top. You can also add a
>   method attribute to limit the match to a particular HTTP method (GET,
>   POST, PUT etc.).

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/client/edit" access="isAuthenticated" method="GET" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/client/edit" access="hasRole('EDITOR')" method="POST" />
</http>
```

Above means you need to select the url pattern to intercept and what methods you want

Comment: But I guess we cant have some thing like  `<intercept-url pattern="/client/edit" access="hasRole('EDITOR')" method="POST, OPTIONS" />` . Right ?

Comment: According to http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd, I dont think so

Comment: How would this work in case of @PreAuthorize annotation, I want Put methods to have Admin access and Post methods to have User access

Comment: What will be it's equivalent in java config

Comment: please have a look on my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579277/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-th

Answer (score 153):

If you're using an annotation based security config file (`@EnableWebSecurity` & `@Configuration`) you can do something like the following in the `configure()` method to allow for the `OPTION` requests to be permitted by Spring Security without authentication for a given path:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
     http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/path/to/allow").permitAll()//allow CORS option calls
      .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what we did to enable CORS OPTIONS requests.

Comment: it's works fine Thanks for your tips i searching and debug lot but can't fixed now i fixed it to use this tips

Comment: I found your answer while researching a similar problem which does not yet respond to your solution in its present form.  Are you willing to take a look?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705874/request-options-logout-doesnt-match-post-logout

Comment: This might help for a general understanding: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

Comment: I am not Java Spring user myself, I am having same issue on my end using different language on backend. Does Java/Spring bring any additional abstraction in security or it is mostly safe to ignore authentication middleware method for all OPTIONS requests?

Comment: Not working for me. Here is my problem, could you please have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579277/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-th

Comment: That works for me.
Remember the difference from one asterisk and double asterisk regards to paths. 

antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/rest/auth/**").permitAll()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569308/spring-difference-of-and-with-regards-to-paths

Comment: In order to open a POST endpoint for client requests it is available the following security configuration: .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/path/to/post/request")

Comment: This is not recommended and don't do this.

Comment: Simple solution in spring security just add http.cors(). You are done.

Comment: A small note: .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**") should be the first on the list of matchers, othervice a preceeding matcher with a more detailed path pattern can be triggered.

Answer (score 53):

Allow all OPTIONS in context:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }
```

Comment: This seemed to be the only way to allow OPTIONS requests without requiring auhorization.

Comment: If you then create an Options endpoint you want to secure, you'll forget about the exclusion in your config and everyone can access it. You should consider using the filter to allow cors option requests to be excluded from spring-security: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html

Comment: With HttpSecurity is http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/registrybrain/**").permitAll()

Comment: Spent more than 2 hours trying and finding solution- only this worked.

Comment: "If you then create an Options endpoint you want to secure" @Tim why would anyone need that?

Comment: Dude you saved me. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is not recommended and you shold not do that.
Below is the correct way for CORS setup of Spring Security and jQuery's ajax.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(userAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors() // <-- This let it use "corsConfigurationSource" bean.
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    protected CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));

        // NOTE: setAllowCredentials(true) is important,
        // otherwise, the value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
        // must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        // NOTE: setAllowedHeaders is important!
        // Without it, OPTIONS preflight request will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
                "Authorization",
                "Accept",
                "Cache-Control",
                "Content-Type",
                "Origin",
                "x-csrf-token",
                "x-requested-with"
        ));

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

And from jQuery side.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // NOTE: Necessary for CORS
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is looking for an easy solution using Spring Boot. Just add an additional bean:

```
   @Bean
   public IgnoredRequestCustomizer optionsIgnoredRequestsCustomizer() {
      return configurer -> {
         List<RequestMatcher> matchers = new ArrayList<>();
         matchers.add(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", "OPTIONS"));
         configurer.requestMatchers(new OrRequestMatcher(matchers));
      };
   }
```

Please note that depending on your application this may open it for potential exploits.

Opened issue for a better solution: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4448

Comment: `IgnoredRequestCustomizer` is deprecated since spring boot 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using annotation-based security config then you should add spring's `CorsFilter` to the application context by calling `.cors()` in your config, something like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
     http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .cors();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In some cases, it is needed add `configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type"));` to `corsConfigurationSource()` when using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to solve the cors problem.