# Is it safe to ignore Authentication for all HTTP.OPTIONS calls?

Tags: angularjs, spring, http, authentication, spring-security

I have a cross origin request to my service. The service expects a "Authentication" header to be a token.

The web client uses angularjs interceptor to pass the Authorization token, but gets

`OPTIONS http://<domain>:<port>/xxxx 401 (Unauthorized)`
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<domain>:<port>/xxxx. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401`

And hence, couldn't get the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With`  as the response. So the `Authorization` header in the following `GET` call is ignored!

But when i disabled the authentication for the `OPTIONS` method -- i added a `antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()` -- 
 the web app was able to send `Authorization` header as expected.

Is it safe to have non-authenticated calls for all `HTTP.OPTIONS` method in my service?

Related question : [Disable Spring Security for OPTIONS Http Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696592/disable-spring-security-for-options-http-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OPTIONS call is a way for the browser to establish whether or not the cross origin call to the API is allowed or not. The browser won't send the `Authorization` header on this call.

You just return a status code indicating whether the cross origin call is allowed (200 OK or 403 Forbidden). If allowed, the browser will make the actual request with the `Authorization` header and then you check the credentials.