# Spring Boot - Interceptor: Exclude path only in GET request

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on a Java Spring project and we wrote an Interceptor for security. This class implements WebMvcConfigurer, and we override the **addInterceptors** method:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new SecurityInterceptor(aService, sService))
                .excludePathPatterns("/", "/ping", "/resc")
        }
```

This works nicely.
Now, the path "/resc" has a GET request but also a POST request. The point is the POST request must be *intercepted* and GET request to same path not.

Is there a way to achieve that?
Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure this already has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26848692, you need to replace OPTIONS with GET and the paths with your paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [InterceptorRegistration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.html) does not provide any methods for your purpose.
But I think there is a way to achive your behavior. You can autowire the ApplicationContext. And than do this inside your Interceptor:

```
try {
  RequestMappingHandlerMapping req2HandlerMapping = (RequestMappingHandlerMapping)applicationContext.getBean("requestMappingHandlerMapping");
  HandlerExecutionChain handlerExeChain = req2HandlerMapping.getHandler(request);
  if (Objects.nonNull(handlerExeChain)) {
     Method method = ((HandlerMethod) handlerExeChain.getHandler()).getMethod();
     if (!method.isAnnotationPresent(GetMapping.class)) {
       //Provide your Security Checks here.
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
  //provide some Error Code
}
```

If you also want to chekc a specific path. For example your "/resc" you can check that es well with an additional if.

Comment: Finally, I use the request in the Interceptor. With that, I obtain the specific path and the method in use. Thanks for help