# Spring OAuth2 authentication with token

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have this SpringBoot app, which uses the OAuth2 login via Google. And it works just fine on it's own.

However, I'm trying to connect it with my React frontend and thus: trying to develop the exchange of tokens.

SecurityConfig

```
http.cors()
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth/**")
      .authenticated()
      .anyRequest()
      .permitAll()
      .and()
      .oauth2Login();
```

Now, I'm obtaining the token this way:

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName());
String token = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
```

and send it to my React client.

The question is: **how to receive and interpret the authorization token at SpringBoot app?**
Right now it's giving me a CORS issue as soon as I attach the `Authoriation` header...

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure the allowed CORS requests in your spring boot app or serve your react frontend from the same domain.

personally ive always done the second option, with the spring boot app serving the react bundle on some url (e.g. /static/js/).

Comment: No, it's not that simple. I have CORS enabled of course...

Comment: Is it an OPTIONS request that is blocked?

Comment: disable the security for the preflight request - e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26848692/5885758

Comment: Man, I'm telling you it's not that simple! It's google endpoint that's blocking me..