# Spring boot: how to match all routes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a simple web application on `Spring boot 1.5.3` and I need all the routes to send static `index.html` file. Now, I have this:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/*")
    public String index(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String url = request.getRequestURI();

        if (url.startsWith("/static")) {
            return String.format("forward:/%s", url);
        }

        return "forward:/static/index.html";
    }
}
```

My application contains only static assets and REST API. But the problem is that the controller shown above only matches the first-level url like `/index`, `/department` etc. I want to match all url levels like `/index/some/other/staff` etc. How can I do that?

PS. I've tried to use the template `/**` in `@RequestMapping`, but my application has broken with the `StackOverflow` error.

**UPDATE**

If add one more level to url, then all will work as expected:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/test/**")
    public String index(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String url = request.getRequestURI();

        if (url.startsWith("/static")) {
            return String.format("forward:/%s", url);
        }

        return "forward:/static/index.html";
    }
}
```

All requests to `/test`, `/test/some/other/staff` will return `index.html`, but I need to start with `/`.

Comment: if you request  /static/index.html directly what happens?

Comment: My application will return index.html.

Comment: then try to forward to the full path of your application?

Comment: Try reading this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569308/spring-difference-of-and-with-regards-to-paths

Comment: @AmerQarabsa, Sorry, but I did not fully understand what I need to do :)

Comment: try like this, return "forward:{full path}/static/index.html";

Comment: @AmerQarabsa, Did not work. StackOverflow exception.

Comment: @RicardoGodoy, I read that topic, but I can resolve my issue with this link.

Comment: Please try /**/*

Comment: @fg78nc, Same result, StackOverflow exception.

Comment: @RequestMapping("/") on class level with @RequestMapping("/*") on method level? or /** on method

Comment: @fg78nc, Already tried first solution, but I need to match all urls, not only first level. Second solution not work for me, please, look at first update.

Comment: my solution here, if already given answers dont work- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004482/3333878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String index(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String url = request.getRequestURI();

    if (url.startsWith("/static")) {
        return String.format("forward:/%s", url);
    }

    return "forward:/static/index.html";
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Above answer didn't really work for me. As per [official Spring doc](https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc) it should be done like this:

```sh
@RequestMapping(value = "{*path}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String handleAll(@PathVariable(value = "path") String path) {
    log.debug("Requested path is: {}", path);
    return "forward:/static/index.html";
}
```